# AlertBox Should wait until user clicks OK to navigate to another activity

Tags: android

Iam using this code for displaying alert whenever required

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LoginSettingsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText ipAddr, port;
Button save, cancel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server_settings);

    // Retrieving IP address and Port entered by user
    ipAddr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_ip_address);
    port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_portno);

    // If Already IP and Port entered and stored in our cache, then bring
    // that and display it
    String ipAddress = ((GlobalClass) LoginSettingsActivity.this
            .getApplication()).getServletIPAddress();
    String portno = ((GlobalClass) LoginSettingsActivity.this
            .getApplication()).getServletPort();
    if (ipAddress != null && ipAddress.length() > 0)
        ipAddr.setText(ipAddress);
    if (portno != null && portno.length() > 0)
        port.setText(portno);

    // After entering Servlet IP and port, submit action handled here. Just
    // storing IP and port in a global storage
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_server_settings);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_server_settings);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View currentButton) {
    switch (currentButton.getId()) {
    case R.id.save_server_settings:
/*          EditText ipAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_ip_address);
        EditText portNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_portno);*/
        //checking if ipadress and port is null or not
        if (ipAddr.length() <= 0 || port.length() <= 0) {
            // LoginAlertDialog("Please make sure IP Address and Port are not empty!",
            // false);
```

here iam getting the alert dialog from pojo class

```
            ((GlobalClass) LoginSettingsActivity.this.getApplication())
                    .SettingsAlertDialog(
                            "Please make sure IP Address and Port are not empty!",
                            LoginSettingsActivity.this, false, null, null);
        } else {
            //Getting ipaddress from the user and setting it in the GlobalClass
            ((GlobalClass) LoginSettingsActivity.this.getApplication())
                    .setServletIPAddress(ipAddr.getText().toString());
            //Getting portno from the user and setting it in the GlobalClass
            ((GlobalClass) LoginSettingsActivity.this.getApplication())
                    .setServletPort(port.getText().toString());
            System.out.println("Inside setting IP and port "
                    + ipAddr.getText().toString() + " "
                    + port.getText().toString());
            // LoginAlertDialog("IP and Port set success!", true);
        /*  ((GlobalClass) LoginSettingsActivity.this.getApplication())
                    .SettingsAlertDialog("IP and Port set success!",
                            LoginSettingsActivity.this, true,
                            LoginSettingsActivity.this,
                            LoginValidation.class);*/
```

here iam creating alert dialog in same activity, both displaying dialog but it closing automatically before i press ok and navigating to another activity.

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginSettingsActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Settings").setMessage("IP and Port set success!").setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {



                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginSettingsActivity.this,
                                        LoginValidation.class);


                                // this addflags should be added, because we are
                                // starting new activity here from outside of the
                                // acutal caller activity.
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                                startActivity(intent);

                                dialog.dismiss();
                                finish();

                            }
                        });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();



        }
    case R.id.cancel_server_settings:
        finish();

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Global class is just a pojo class to set and get. I tried calling alert dialog from pojo class also i used alerrt dialog in same activity but both seems not to work, the dialog close and i get window leaked message.

Iam having a login page if user is not enetring username and password then this alert pops untill user clicks OK it wont get disappear because i need to stay in same page.(the code working fine the alert box stays until user click ok)

The same dialog iam calling in my another activity to save some global values, After clicking save the same dialog appears and it should wait until user clicks OK because here only if user clicks ok then it should navigate to another activity.

But here with out waiting automatically it gets navigate to another activity

Comment: please post your complete code...i think the activity is getting started from some other place....

Comment: please check i have edited, iam getting window leaked message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, just a simple mistake, Forget to use break in switch case statemts,

Here the modified code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View currentButton) {
switch (currentButton.getId()) {
case R.id.save_server_settings:
/*          EditText ipAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_ip_address);
    EditText portNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_portno);*/
    //checking if ipadress and port is null or not
    if (ipAddr.length() <= 0 || port.length() <= 0) {
        // LoginAlertDialog("Please make sure IP Address and Port are not empty!",
        // false);
        ((GlobalClass) LoginSettingsActivity.this.getApplication())
                .SettingsAlertDialog(
                        "Please make sure IP Address and Port are not empty!",
                        LoginSettingsActivity.this, false, null, null);
    } else {
        //Getting ipaddress from the user and setting it in the GlobalClass
        ((GlobalClass) LoginSettingsActivity.this.getApplication())
                .setServletIPAddress(ipAddr.getText().toString());
        //Getting portno from the user and setting it in the GlobalClass
        ((GlobalClass) LoginSettingsActivity.this.getApplication())
                .setServletPort(port.getText().toString());
        System.out.println("Inside setting IP and port "
                + ipAddr.getText().toString() + " "
                + port.getText().toString());
        // LoginAlertDialog("IP and Port set success!", true);
    /*  ((GlobalClass) LoginSettingsActivity.this.getApplication())
                .SettingsAlertDialog("IP and Port set success!",
                        LoginSettingsActivity.this, true,
                        LoginSettingsActivity.this,
                        LoginValidation.class);*/
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginSettingsActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Settings").setMessage("IP and Port set success!").setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {



                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginSettingsActivity.this,
                                    LoginValidation.class);


                            // this addflags should be added, because we are
                            // starting new activity here from outside of the
                            // acutal caller activity.
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                            startActivity(intent);

                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();

                        }
                    });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();



    }
**break;**
case R.id.cancel_server_settings:
    finish();


}
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

super.onDestroy();
}

}
```